# Having unstable layout in App using phonegap & jquery mobile after returning from webview in iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, cordova

Hi Can some one help me out to fix my issue. I am using jquery mobile with cordova to build ios App. When i trigger an external

link from my App and return back to App having unstable layout. Can someone tell why the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you just add code snippets and a screenshot of what is really happening?

Comment: the word 'unstable' is too general :)